# Trying to get Value from Firebase database and creating if else statement to set value in firebase but app executes the fourth line only

Tags: java, android, if-statement, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code.When user clicks button i execute this code

```
finalteamcount.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String one = "one";
                    String two = "two";
                    String three = "three";
                    String four = "four";
                    String qwq = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    if (qwq == null){finalteamcount.setValue(one);}
                    if (qwq == one){finalteamcount.setValue(two);}
                    if (qwq == two){finalteamcount.setValue(three);}
                    if (qwq == three){finalteamcount.setValue(four);}

                }
```

It Directely set four, the value i am retriving is null

Comment: Where do you get `null`? It's often easiest if you add a `Log.i()` in the code that prints the variable, and then show us the updated code and its output.

Comment: there is no data to that location so it will be null?

Comment: You shouldn't use `==` to compare strings in Java. Use `equals()` instead as described in the duplicate.